# Move forward/backward number of characters past end of line in VIM

Tags: vim

How can I move forward/backward number of characters past end of line in VIM?

I known I can type, for example,

> 25l

and go forwards 25 characters, but this command will always stop at the end of a line. Also, there is `25go`, but this goes forward from the beginning of the buffer, not forward from the current cursor position. I want to go forwards a certain number of characters including end of line characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is <kbd>space</kbd> to move forwards and <kbd>backspace</kbd> to move backwards.

<kbd>space</kbd> will continue in the following line. If you want to add spaces in the current line instead of moving to the next one then the `:set virtualedit=onemore` is the option for you.

Comment: This is the right answer. For example, 500[spacebar] moves 500 spaces forward and unlike the L key moves past the end of line.

Answer (score 5):

You can set `virtualedit` option:

```
:set ve=all
```

Virtual editing means that the cursor can be positioned where there is no actual character.

Answer (score 3):

The `'whichwrap'` option determines what motions can move the cursor to another line. By default, none of the left / right movements do that.

The inclusion of `h,l` is not recommended, as some macros and plugins may depend on the original behavior and break - your call to test and decide. But it should be safe to include the <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> cursor keys via (the latter pair is for insert mode and optional)

```
:set whichwrap+=<,>,[,]
```

Then, you can move by 5 characters *across* the line ending via <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>.

Whether the newline character is counted or not depends on the `'virtualedit'` option. To include the newline:

```
:set virtualedit=onemore
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (that doesn't require changing options, but is more verbose) is by using the `search()` function. The following will move the cursor to the right by `6` characters. It does this by matching from the current position (`\%#`) 7 characters including newlines (`\_.`):

```
:call search('\%#\_.\{7}', 'ce')
```